# How to create two tables side by side in flow document

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I want to create two tables side by side in flow document.
I don't want to use blockuicontainer.

Comment: Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909(v=vs.110).aspx FlowControl already has many options built in.

Answer (score 1):

It is all composition, you need to put the two tables inside another table which has the dimensions of one row with two columns, something like this:

```
Table table1 = CreateTable1();
Table table2 = CreateTable2();

var containingTable = new Table();
var containingRowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
var containingColumn1 = new TableColumn();
var containingColumn2 = new TableColumn();

containingTable.Columns.Add(containingColumn1);
containingTable.Columns.Add(containingColumn2);
containingTable.RowGroups.Add(containingRowGroup);

var containingCell1 = new TableCell();
var containingCell2 = new TableCell();

containingCell1.Blocks.Add(new Section(table));
containingCell2.Blocks.Add(new Section(table2));

var containingRow = new TableRow();
containingRow.Cells.Add(containingCell1);
containingRow.Cells.Add(containingCell2);

containingRowGroup.Rows.Add(containingRow);

document.Blocks.Add(new Section(containingTable));
```

Comment: I still sometimes think who designed this :D